# How to tell cxf to keep the wrapper types in methods?

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

In my WSDL I have an operation

```
<wsdl:operation name="theMethod">
    <wsdl:input message="input1" name="input1"></wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:classNumber1" name="classNumber1"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

in my xsd, `classNumber1` is a complex type and it is a wrapper for another type: classNumber2

```
<xs:complexType name="classNumber1">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="tns:classNumber2"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

when I generate classes with cxf (I use cxf maven plugin), I expected that `theMethod` to return a `ClassNumber1` but it was a `ClassNumber2`.

```
@WebMethod
@ResponseWrapper(localName="classNumber1" , className="com.model.ClassNumber")
public ClassNumber2 theMethod (Input1 input1){
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to tell cxf to generate the method with the wrapper CLassNumber1.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is your method which returns ClassNumber1? Is it inside ClassNumber1? or somewhere else. please elaborate the question.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Can you post Message element for this method theMethod. <message name="classNumber1">
      <part name="firstName" type="xsd:classNumber1"/>
   </message>

Comment: `<wsdl:message name="classNumber1">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:classNumber1"name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>`

Comment: AFAIK what the plugin does is right. Do you have a element '<xs:element name="className1" type="tns:classNumber1"/>'

Comment: Yes I have this in my xsd

Comment: its really difficult to suggest solution with this little amount of info. I need to know whether you have created the types in wsdl file or do you import from xsd.  you might be referring to wrong elements by using namespace prefix. If possible please post the complete wsdl .

Comment: I don't think it is question of types, it is rather related to serialization and encapsulation and how serialization  is done by cxf.

Comment: I think that cxf maybe breaks somehow the encapsulation to simplify the object

Comment: I suspected because you have tns: prefix for classNumber1 but not to input.

Comment: I used a simple example because my actual example is more complex, I would like to share it but I am afraid it is a bit confidential

Comment: I can understand that, No worries.

Comment: This topic is not related to serialization for sure. :)

Comment: I updated my request,I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the solution in this [doc](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html), question "*How can I switch my generated web service method calls from wrapper style to non wrapper-style (or vice-versa)?*"

The solution to keep wrappers with cxf generation is to add a **binding file** in the pom.xml:

```
<defaultOptions>
<bindingFiles>
    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
</bindingFiles>
<noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
</defaultOptions>
```

In the binding file you set **enableWrapperStyle** to false:

```
<jaxws:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided I have created a basic interface as shown below.

this works as per your expectation.

```
        <xsd:complexType name="input1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="in" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="ClassNumber1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="out" type="tns:ClassNumber2" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="ClassNumber2">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="out" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="input1">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:input1" name="parameters" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ClassNumber1">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ClassNumber1" name="parameters" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="NewWSDLFile">
    <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:input1" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:ClassNumber1" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="NewWSDLFileSOAP" type="tns:NewWSDLFile">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/NewOperation" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="NewWSDLFile">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:NewWSDLFileSOAP" name="NewWSDLFileSOAP">
        <soap:address location="http://www.example.org/" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Please check `<wsdl:output message="tns:ClassNumber1" />`

I believe you have given the wrong  in your output information in your

```
<wsdl:message name="ClassNumber1">
            <wsdl:part element="tns:ClassNumber1" name="parameters" />
        </wsdl:message>
```

Hope this helps.