# Send a SOAP request to a remote web service and get a response using apache Camel

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-camel

I'm doing a development to send a `SOAP` request to a remote web service and get a response using `apache Camel`.

In this case, I succesfully generated Client Side wsdl2java Code using the `cxf-codegen-plugin` for the WSDl mentioned below.

- Sample WSDL URL : `http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL`

And after doing some researches, I created below sample code to send a SOAP request to the web service defined in there and get a response with apache Camel using the generated client code.

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

HttpComponent httpComponent = new HttpComponent();
context.addComponent("http", httpComponent);

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

GetQuote getQuote = new GetQuote();
getQuote.setSymbol("test123");

GetQuoteResponse getQuoteResponse = template.requestBody("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx",getQuote, GetQuoteResponse.class);

System.out.println(getQuoteResponse);
```

But it gives below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: net.webservicex.GetQuote@10bdf5e5 of type: net.webservicex.GetQuote on: Message[ID-namal-PC-33172-1469806939935-0-1]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: net.webservicex.GetQuote to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value net.webservicex.GetQuote@10bdf5e5. Exchange[ID-namal-PC-33172-1469806939935-0-2]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: net.webservicex.GetQuote to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value net.webservicex.GetQuote@10bdf5e5]

Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: net.webservicex.GetQuote to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value net.webservicex.GetQuote@10bdf5e5
```

**What have I miss here? Data binding? or anything else? I generated the client code using cxf so how I can send this using cxf?**

**What I simply want is to send a SOAP request to a remote web service and get a response using apache Camel.**

- Camel Version : 2.9.0
- Java Version : 1.7.x / 1.8.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use the CXF component for this. Depending on how the CXF code is generated you might just send & receive a string instead of an object in your example - see [How to tell cxf to keep the wrapper types in methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270996/how-to-tell-cxf-to-keep-the-wrapper-types-in-methods) for more information.

Here's your example with CXF.

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

CxfComponent cxfComponent = new CxfComponent(context);
CxfEndpoint serviceEndpoint =
    new CxfEndpoint("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx", cxfComponent);

// Service class generated by CXF codegen plugin.
serviceEndpoint.setServiceClass(StockQuoteSoap.class);

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

// Request and response can be 'bare' or 'wrapped', see the service class.
String getQuoteResponse = template.requestBody(serviceEndpoint, "MSFT", String.class);

System.out.println(getQuoteResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you very much bgossit! It is working fine for this. I have one question. How to send the request body if it takes multiple paramaters. eg : how to send request parameters (messageHeader, securityHeader, sessionCreateRQ) for a below like invocation (SessionCreateRS sessionCreateRS = sessionCreatePortType.sessionCreateRQ(messageHeader, securityHeader, sessionCreateRQ); //This is from JAX-WS )

Comment: Oh I had a dumb answer.. I simply added them to a list and sent. It worked! Please share any better answer.