# Send multiple parameters as the requestBody using Apache Camel ProdcerTemplate with CxfComponent

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

As per the instructions mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662895/send-a-soap-request-to-a-remote-web-service-and-get-a-response-using-apache-came#comment64748213_38682755) and with the help of some other sources, I have created a SoapClient to send a SOAP request and get a response using Apahe Camel.

**Code :**

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

CxfComponent cxfComponent = new CxfComponent(context);
CxfEndpoint serviceEndpoint =
    new CxfEndpoint("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx", cxfComponent);

serviceEndpoint.setServiceClass(StockQuoteSoap.class);

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

String getQuoteResponse = template.requestBody(serviceEndpoint, "test123", String.class);

System.out.println(getQuoteResponse);
```

**Adjuscent JAX-WS invocation :**

```
String response = stockQuoteSoap.getQuote("test123")    // stockQuoteSoap is created with JaxWsProxyFactoryBean using the ServiceClass StockQuoteSoap
```

This is working fine for the Web Services expecting only one parameters as the request body. I want to know how I can send multiple parameters as the request body? (I tired requestBodyAndHeader, assyncRequestBodyAndHeader etc).

**Adjuscent JAX-WS invocation :**

```
SessionCreateRS sessionCreateRS = sessionCreatePortType.sessionCreateRQ(messageHeader, securityHeader, sessionCreateRQ);  // sessionCreatePortType is created with JaxWsProxyFactoryBean using the ServiceClass SessionCreatePortType. messageHeader, securityHeader, sessionCreateRQ are in the type of WS generated with cxf-codegen-plugging.
```

In this case, it always looks for the messageHeader as the request body I don't know how to send the other parameters using Producertemplate with CXFContext. In JAX-WS it is perfectly working when sending all parameters in above way.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I had a dumb answer..
I simply added them to a list and sent. It worked!

```
ArrayList requestBody = new ArrayList();
requestBody.add(messageHeader);
requestBody.add(security);
requestBody.add(sessionCreateRQ);

SessionCreateRS sessionCreateRS = template.requestBody(serviceEndpoint, requestBody, SessionCreateRS.class);
```

Please share any better answer.